# Redeclare variable inside enum

Tags: c++, c, enums, language-lawyer, declaration

In C, If we re-declare variable inside `enum`, then compiler gives an error that "'i' redeclared as different kind of symbol".It Ok.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 10;

struct S 
{ 
    enum 
    {
        i = 20
    }e; 
};

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

But, In C++, If we redeclare variable inside enum, then it's working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i = 10;

struct S 
{ 
    enum 
    {
        i = 20
    }e; 
};

int main()
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

I don't understand, Why doesn't C++ compiler gives an error for redeclaration variable?

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages, even though they share a lot of the syntax. One such thing is how enumerations work. Just because something looks the same in C and C++, doesn't mean they actually are the same.

Comment: @KeineLust I believe that is only true with `enum class`. Ordinary C-style enums are still defined in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Your C++ compiler doesn't give an error because it follows C++ language rules, rather than C language rules. If it followed C rules it would be a C compiler, wouldn't it?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, you are right, I misread the question

Comment: For enumerations, you might want to see e.g. [this C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum) and [this C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Comment: That one exemple of why C is not C++ is not C. By the way, finally a question correctly tagged as C and C++ \o/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't give a re-declaration error because the enumerator is introduced into class scope. Recall that a struct and class are mostly interchangeable in C++. The scope of `S` contains the enumerator `i`.

In C however, `struct S` doesn't define a scope. There are only 4 types of scope in C: function, file, block, and function prototype. As such, `i` is introduced into file scope where the variable `i` is already defined.